# CSS Bootstrap : 2 column form with label on the left

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've been trying for 3 hours to make a 2 column form with the label aligned on the left, but i am really not getting it. I've read bootstrap documentation, tried to play with "row" class but i dont have the result i want.
Here's a picture of what i'm trying to do, it has to be in 1 form. I've seen a lot of question about this, but no one seems to fit my problem ( people wanted them vertical aligned or within 2 different forms )

If anyone can show me the way to do it, and if possible, some explanation about how to align things using rows, it would be awesome !

[image: 2 column form]

Comment: Can you drop your code in a quick fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this ;)

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Test</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input class="form-control">
        </div>
      </div>
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Test</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input class="form-control">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ttyneyq9/

Comment: saved me! great solution.

Answer (score 1):

You say 2 columns, but this configuration looks to me like it should be 4 columns. Because the labels should be their own column, and the textboxes should also be their own.

Something like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-2">label</div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">textbox</div>
  <div class="col-sm-2">label in "2nd" column</div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">textbox in "2nd" column</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-2">label</div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">textbox</div>
  <div class="col-sm-2">label in "2nd" column</div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">textbox in "2nd" column</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-2">label</div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">textbox</div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 text-right"><a href="#">Pay by Phone/SMS</a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow thanks guys ! Im particulary sorry cause i just have noticed that the comment i made weeks ago wasnt posted ( probably my fault ).

Comment: Wow im sorry guys, i posted a comment weeks ago but i just noticed something went wrong ! so thanks everybody, it worked :)

Comment: saved my day.. Thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

> I've been trying for 3 hours to make a 2 column form with the label aligned on the left, but i am really not getting it.

Because it's a form, you should really take advantage of Bootstraps `.form-control` and `.form-group` classes. Here is a sample fiddle for you to review http://jsfiddle.net/yongchuc/hzktphu6/. Bootstrap reference can be found here as well: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't be too bad. You can do it a couple ways:

1) Split each row up into 4 columns

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2"><label for="Username">Username</label></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"><input type="text" name="Username" /></div>
    <div class="col-md-2"><label for="Membership">Membership></label></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"><select name="Membership"></select></div>
</div>
<!-- Add other rows for both columns -->
```

2) Use nested rows/columns

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3"><label for="Username">Username</label></div>
            <div class="col-md-9"><input type="text" name="Username" /></div>
        </div>
        <!-- Add other rows for first column -->
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3"><label for="Membership">Username</label></div>
            <div class="col-md-9"><select name="Membership"></select></div>
        </div>
        <!-- Add other rows for the second column -->
    </div>
</div>
```

In Bootstrap, each row consists of 12 columns by default. The column span is specified in the CSS class for each column (e.g. "col-md-3" will span 3 columns on medium sized screens or larger, for smaller screens the labels will go above the input). You'll just have to adjust the column spans to your liking.

Answer (score 0):

For me it will be something like that

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3"><label>Username</label></div>
            <div class="col-md-9"><input type="text" name="Username" class="form-control" /></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3"><label>Password</label></div>
            <div class="col-md-9"><input type="password" name="Password" class="form-control" /></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3"><label>Email</label></div>
            <div class="col-md-9"><input type="email" name="Email" class="form-control" /></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3"><label>Membership</label></div>
            <div class="col-md-9"><select name="Membership">----options------</select></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3"><label>Payment</label></div>
            <div class="col-md-9"><select name="Payment">----options------</select></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the reason why this is the better solution is because when it's displayed on mobile they will show below each others in the same order as they're written above

Answer (score 0):

```
                       <form class="form-horizontal">
                          <div class="col-xs-6 form-group">
                              <label for="inputEmail" class="control-label col-xs-4">Valet Parking</label>
                              <div class="col-xs-8">
                                  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email">
                              </div>
                          </div>
                           <div class="col-xs-6 form-group">
                              <label for="inputEmail" class="control-label col-xs-4">Kids menus</label>
                              <div class="col-xs-8">
                                  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email">
                              </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-xs-6 form-group">
                              <label for="inputPassword" class="control-label col-xs-4">Car Parking</label>
                              <div class="col-xs-8">
                                  <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password">
                              </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-xs-6 form-group">
                              <label for="inputPassword" class="control-label col-xs-4">High chairs</label>
                              <div class="col-xs-8">
                                  <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password">
                              </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-xs-6 form-group">
                              <label for="inputEmail" class="control-label col-xs-4">Internet</label>
                              <div class="col-xs-8">
                                  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email">
                              </div>
                          </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-6 form-group">
                              <label for="inputEmail" class="control-label col-xs-4">Play areas</label>
                              <div class="col-xs-8">
                                  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email">
                              </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-xs-6 form-group">
                              <label for="inputPassword" class="control-label col-xs-4">TVs</label>
                              <div class="col-xs-8">
                                  <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password">
                              </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-xs-6 form-group">
                              <label for="inputPassword" class="control-label col-xs-4">Handicap accessible</label>
                              <div class="col-xs-8">
                                  <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password">
                              </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-xs-6 form-group">
                              <label for="inputEmail" class="control-label col-xs-4">Outdoor seating</label>
                              <div class="col-xs-8">
                                  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email">
                              </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-xs-6 form-group">
                              <label for="inputPassword" class="control-label col-xs-4">Pets</label>
                              <div class="col-xs-8">
                                  <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password">
                              </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-xs-6 form-group">
                              <label for="inputPassword" class="control-label col-xs-4">Smoking areas</label>
                              <div class="col-xs-8">
                                  <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password">
                              </div>
                          </div>          
                      </form>
```

Comment: Please use these and let me know. Dont forget to add bootstrap css and js

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.

Comment: Well if anyone asked question here for bootstrap. He/She is aware of the bootstrap css and js, and i used the code in my own project.